# Oracle APEX Web Service Logs

Tags: rest, web-services, logging, plsql, oracle-apex

Does APEX offer a logging mechanism for Web Services made using the "RESTful Services" wizard?

I've tried adding apex_debug calls but can these logs be referenced with the Debug Window?

Version: Application Express 5.1.1.00.08

Comment: I think I saw that one exists for 18.x

Comment: Are you asking for logs related to consuming (calling) a REST Service from an APEX application?  Or are you asking about REST Services that you have defined, and logs associated with the callers of those REST Services?

Comment: I was talking about the REST Services that I have defined. I have added PL/SQL code on the "Resource Handler" part. I wanted to put debug logs on the PL/SQL handler and also wanted to ask whether  header information, body information. etc are logged somewhere?

Comment: Here is a late reference for more info http://jastraub.blogspot.com/2018/03/apex-181-new-feature-logging-web.html